# Exit status 1 when trying to pip install audioread

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

im trying to install `audioread` but it keeps getting errors.
Error log:

```
jared@jared-desktop:~$ sudo -H python3 -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org audioread       
[sudo] password for jared: 
Collecting audioread
  Downloading audioread-2.1.8.tar.gz (21 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ewyyxjpn/audioread/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-ewyyxjpn/audioread/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-ewyyxjpn/audioread/pip-egg-info        
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-ewyyxjpn/audioread/                                      
    Complete output (113 lines):                                                        
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /packages/16/45/81b5262c0efc08882bdf183b788e6d28e3d684863990996d8b60967d48da/pytest_runner-5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl               
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /packages/16/45/81b5262c0efc08882bdf183b788e6d28e3d684863990996d8b60967d48da/pytest_runner-5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl               
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /packages/16/45/81b5262c0efc08882bdf183b788e6d28e3d684863990996d8b60967d48da/pytest_runner-5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl               
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /packages/16/45/81b5262c0efc08882bdf183b788e6d28e3d684863990996d8b60967d48da/pytest_runner-5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl               
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /packages/16/45/81b5262c0efc08882bdf183b788e6d28e3d684863990996d8b60967d48da/pytest_runner-5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl               
    ERROR: Exception:                                                                   
    Traceback (most recent call last):                                                  
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen                                                                 
        chunked=chunked,                                                                
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request                                                           
        self._validate_conn(conn)                                                       
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 994, in _validate_conn                                                          
        conn.connect()                                                                  
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connection.py", line 394, in connect                                                                     
        ssl_context=context,                                                            
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 370, in ssl_wrap_socket                                                              
        return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)               
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket                        
        _context=self, _session=session)                                                
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 817, in __init__                           
        self.do_handshake()                                                             
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1077, in do_handshake                      
        self._sslobj.do_handshake()                                                     
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake                       
        self._sslobj.do_handshake()                                                     
    ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)                                                                                       

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                 

    Traceback (most recent call last):                                                  
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send                                                                         
        timeout=timeout                                                                 
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 760, in urlopen                                                                 
        **response_kw                                                                   
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 760, in urlopen                                                                 
        **response_kw                                                                   
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 760, in urlopen                                                                 
        **response_kw                                                                   
      [Previous line repeated 2 more times]                                             
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 720, in urlopen                                                                 
        method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]                 
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 436, in increment                                                                   
        raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))                  
    pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/16/45/81b5262c0efc08882bdf183b788e6d28e3d684863990996d8b60967d48da/pytest_runner-5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),))                                                                        

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                 

    Traceback (most recent call last):                                                  
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 186, in _main                                                                       
        status = self.run(options, args)                                                
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/wheel.py", line 161, in run                                                                           
        resolver.resolve(requirement_set)                                               
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 177, in resolve                                                                       
        discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))                 
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 333, in _resolve_one                                                                  
        abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)                     
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 282, in _get_abstract_dist_for                                                        
        abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)                   
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 482, in prepare_linked_requirement                                                
        hashes=hashes,                                                                  
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 287, in unpack_url                                                                
        hashes=hashes,                                                                  
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 159, in unpack_http_url                                                           
        link, downloader, temp_dir.path, hashes                                         
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 299, in _download_http_url                                                        
        download = downloader(link)                                                     
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/download.py", line 189, in __call__                                                                    
        resp = _http_get_download(self._session, link)                                  
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/download.py", line 157, in _http_get_download                                                          
        stream=True,                                                                    
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 546, in get                                                                          
        return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)                                       
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 405, in request                                                                      
        return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)            
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request                                                                      
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)                                           
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send                                                                         
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 53, in send
        resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
        raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    pip._vendor.requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/16/45/81b5262c0efc08882bdf183b788e6d28e3d684863990996d8b60967d48da/pytest_runner-5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
        subprocess.check_call(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmp_ob5jmrv', '--quiet', 'pytest-runner']' returned non-zero exit status 2.

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-ewyyxjpn/audioread/setup.py", line 58, in <module>
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 144, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 139, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 721, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 783, in resolve
        replace_conflicting=replace_conflicting
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1066, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1078, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 777, in fetch_build_egg
        return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 130, in fetch_build_egg
        raise DistutilsError(str(e))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmp_ob5jmrv', '--quiet', 'pytest-runner']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have also tried downloading `audioread` manually and installing it locally, but I got this error:

```
jared@jared-desktop:~$ sudo -H python3 -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --trusted-host pypi.org /home/jared/Downloads/audioread-2.1.8.tar.gz            
Processing ./Downloads/audioread-2.1.8.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-3o2pmtqr/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-3o2pmtqr/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-req-build-3o2pmtqr/pip-egg-info                                
         cwd: /tmp/pip-req-build-3o2pmtqr/                                              
    Complete output (113 lines):                                                        
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /packages/16/45/81b5262c0efc08882bdf183b788e6d28e3d684863990996d8b60967d48da/pytest_runner-5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl               
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /packages/16/45/81b5262c0efc08882bdf183b788e6d28e3d684863990996d8b60967d48da/pytest_runner-5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl               
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /packages/16/45/81b5262c0efc08882bdf183b788e6d28e3d684863990996d8b60967d48da/pytest_runner-5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl               
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /packages/16/45/81b5262c0efc08882bdf183b788e6d28e3d684863990996d8b60967d48da/pytest_runner-5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl               
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),)': /packages/16/45/81b5262c0efc08882bdf183b788e6d28e3d684863990996d8b60967d48da/pytest_runner-5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl               
    ERROR: Exception:                                                                   
    Traceback (most recent call last):                                                  
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen                                                                 
        chunked=chunked,                                                                
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 376, in _make_request                                                           
        self._validate_conn(conn)                                                       
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 994, in _validate_conn                                                          
        conn.connect()                                                                  
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connection.py", line 394, in connect                                                                     
        ssl_context=context,                                                            
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 370, in ssl_wrap_socket                                                              
        return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)               
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 407, in wrap_socket                        
        _context=self, _session=session)                                                
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 817, in __init__                           
        self.do_handshake()                                                             
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1077, in do_handshake                      
        self._sslobj.do_handshake()                                                     
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/ssl.py", line 689, in do_handshake                       
        self._sslobj.do_handshake()                                                     
    ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)                                                                                       

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                 

    Traceback (most recent call last):                                                  
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send                                                                         
        timeout=timeout                                                                 
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 760, in urlopen                                                                 
        **response_kw                                                                   
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 760, in urlopen                                                                 
        **response_kw                                                                   
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 760, in urlopen                                                                 
        **response_kw                                                                   
      [Previous line repeated 2 more times]                                             
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 720, in urlopen                                                                 
        method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]                 
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 436, in increment                                                                   
        raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))                  
    pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/16/45/81b5262c0efc08882bdf183b788e6d28e3d684863990996d8b60967d48da/pytest_runner-5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),))                                                                        

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:                 

    Traceback (most recent call last):                                                  
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 186, in _main                                                                       
        status = self.run(options, args)                                                
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/commands/wheel.py", line 161, in run                                                                           
        resolver.resolve(requirement_set)                                               
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 177, in resolve                                                                       
        discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))                 
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 333, in _resolve_one                                                                  
        abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)                     
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/legacy_resolve.py", line 282, in _get_abstract_dist_for                                                        
        abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)                   
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 482, in prepare_linked_requirement                                                
        hashes=hashes,                                                                  
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 287, in unpack_url                                                                
        hashes=hashes,                                                                  
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 159, in unpack_http_url                                                           
        link, downloader, temp_dir.path, hashes                                         
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/operations/prepare.py", line 299, in _download_http_url                                                        
        download = downloader(link)                                                     
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/download.py", line 189, in __call__                                                                    
        resp = _http_get_download(self._session, link)                                  
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/download.py", line 157, in _http_get_download                                                          
        stream=True,                                                                    
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 546, in get                                                                          
        return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)                                       
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 405, in request                                                                      
        return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)            
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request                                                                      
        resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)                                           
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send                                                                         
        r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 53, in send
        resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
        raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    pip._vendor.requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/16/45/81b5262c0efc08882bdf183b788e6d28e3d684863990996d8b60967d48da/pytest_runner-5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:852)'),))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
        subprocess.check_call(cmd)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 311, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmpqwo6z9bm', '--quiet', 'pytest-runner']' returned non-zero exit status 2.

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):



etc... (its a long error)


        raise DistutilsError(str(e))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/tmp/tmpqwo6z9bm', '--quiet', 'pytest-runner']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I also have tried extracting the `tar.gz` file and installing it like that, but that didn't work either. Could anyone help me with this?

If anyone is wondering:
I am using python 3.6.
My pip is up to date.
My system is up to date...

Answer (score 0):

Installing the version 2.1.6 works just fine.

```
pip install audioread==2.1.6
```

But I'm not sure why newer version doesn't work..

Comment: Im just getting this error when trying to install `2.1.6`. `ERROR: THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE.`

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the setuptools and wheel worked for me. Run `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel` on cmd. Then re-install the package